# Latex: Any way to have a caption on the table that won't show up in the list of tables?

Tags: latex

What I'm trying to do is this:

table
caption text. Adapted from (source, year)

In the list of tables, I'd like the "caption text" to show up, but not the source. However, if I put it all in the `caption{}`, they do.

Ooooooooh, I just realized that if I put the "Adapted from `\cite{source}`" inside the `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` but after the tabular, I can get the text there without showing up at the list of tables. But if there's a better way to do it let me know.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm sure the people at the new beta site for Tex, Latex and friends at http://tex.stackexchange.com could help you with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions):

```
\caption[caption text.]{caption text. Adapted from (source, year)}
```